# 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement Spring application which uses 2 databases. I tried this:

application.properties

```
spring.production.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/production_gateway
spring.production.datasource.username=wildfly
spring.production.datasource.password=qwerty
spring.production.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.production.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.production.datasource.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.production.datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.warehouse.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/production_warehouse
spring.warehouse.datasource.username=wildfly
spring.warehouse.datasource.password=qwerty
spring.warehouse.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.warehouse.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.warehouse.datasource.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.warehouse.datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Configuration Bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.plugin.production.service", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "productionEntityManagerFactory", 
        transactionManagerRef = "productionTransactionManager"
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextProductionDatasource {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production.datasource")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(userDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.plugin.production.service" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production.datasource")
    public DataSource userDataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionTransactionManager")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.production.datasource")
    public PlatformTransactionManager productionTransactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionExceptionTranslation")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.production.datasource")
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor productionExceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

But when I start the application I get error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Have you excluded DataSourceAutoconfiguration.class?

Comment: No, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class:

```
  @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: One additional question: I found this: https://blogs.ashrithgn.com/multiple-data-source-in-spring-boot-using-spring-boot-data-starter/ Should I use this specific config when I use Hikari CP?

Comment: Yep if you want to have reusable connections but not to create every time new one

Comment: Does it helped ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the advice. One more question: I want to use Spring profiles. What is the recommended way to use configuration for many cases: application.properties file for every profile?

Comment: Yes for every profile please create spring-profile_name.yml or .properties .In application.yml or properties you can have shared configuration

Comment: @PeterPenzov please approve if my answer is valid